# caps2esc stopped working with systemd problem

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl, libudev

I'm running Manjaro 18.1.0 and using the [interception-caps2esc](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc) 0.1.3-2 plugin via AUR. My `/etc/udevmon.yaml` and `/etc/systemd/system/udevmon.service` are setup as described in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979359/how-do-i-install-caps2esc). This has been working fine for months, but has now suddenly stopped working. I tried re-booting.

I'm quite stumped as to what's caused the difference. I notice, however, that running `systemctl status udevmon.service` returns

```
● udevmon.service - udevmon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/udevmon.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-10-13 16:34:06 CEST; 20min ago
 Main PID: 7749 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)

Oct 13 16:34:06 my-pc systemd[1]: Started udevmon.
Oct 13 16:34:06 my-pc systemd[1]: udevmon.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Oct 13 16:34:06 my-pc systemd[1]: udevmon.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

which I suppose is relevant. `systemctl reset-failed` does not help, and my understanding of `systemd` and the workings of `caps2esc` is too limited to identify relevant next steps for solving this problem or for troubleshooting.

My question: **What steps can I take to resolve or further troubleshoot this issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue and was able to resolve it by reinstalling `interception-tools` and `interception-caps2esc` (I'm using `yay`):

```
yay -S interception-tools
yay -S interception-caps2esc
```

And then restarting the `udevmon` service:

```
sudo systemctl restart udevmon.service
```

I can't explain why it broke or why this fixes it but it did for me.